# Looking for timer by service and task to group and import

Tags: invoices

I've been struggling with connecting my various system and having only enough tools to make my freelancing work and invoicing flow efficient. I've been using Freshbooks for invoicing and Asana for project management details.

Now I'd really like to add something to automate my leads, onboarding, and wrap up tasks and after trying out Dubsado, Bonsai, and 17Hats, I'm settling on HoneyBook for handling onboarding with automated workflows. However, all of these lack in some important timing and invoicing pieces that I need. I have fixed and hourly projects both. So I need to time against my fixed projects per service with budget notifications, AND need to record billable time for the occasional custom requested task at an hourly rate.

My issue with many of the timers in my final 3 is that they don't register against the estimate and if they are per task, those aren't grouped together in a final invoice but a lot of single items that have to added up. Leading to a lot of manual tinkering per invoice time.

Do I pull in a 4th tool that is just my master timer that can integrate? One that can do fixed projects (hopefully imported or zapped in) and group hours on custom tasks into one line item to be added to either invoicing system?

Has anyone found a good way to connect all of these?

Thanks for your suggestions.